# /tmp is yet not ready or not present

Tags: 12.04, tmp

After pressing power bottom, when Ubuntu shows the login screen it also shows this error
*the drive for /tmp is yet not ready or not present*.
Why is this displayed?
And how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused if /tmp as previously mounted to a drive or partition that has been removed or Ubuntu is having trouble recognizing.

The first place to look would be in fstab this will list the parts of the file system and where they are mounted. Look at the line with /tmp and check what drive it is mounted to it might be something like /dev/sdb1  this will correspond to a physical drive that may have been removed or failed.

Posting the output of fstab would be quite helpful.

Comment: Would you please elaborate and make it clear. Still I am confused.

Comment: run the following command and post the output '$cat /etc/fstab'  also post the output of '$df -h'  these will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: # Use'blkid'to print universally unique identifier for
# device;this may be used with UUID= as more robust wayto name devices
# thatworks even if disks are added and removed.Seefstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f068162b-39bd-4291-8cac-be6f3d5b9e69 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=a07d7ebd-dba6-4230-856b-ea1bbfff925e none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       170G  8.2G  154G   6% /
udev            924M  4.0K  924M   1% /dev
tmpfs           374M  1.1M  373M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            933M  160K  933M   1% /run/shm